# VBA to find a table by name and then paste to next empty row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with a number of sheets.

[image]
[image]

I am trying to copy data in cell D4 from a sheet named "A", find a table in "Sheet 1" that matches the data in C4 in sheet "A" and then past to next empty row in that table.

So far I have this:

```
Range("D4").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet 1").Select
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Which works fine for pasting data to the next empty row of Column A but I can't work out how to make it find the correct column based on the data in C4 on sheet "A".

I have this

```
Application.Match(C4,Sheet1!1:1,0)
```

which works to match the data but I can't work out how to fit it in to the code?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry I meant to post pictures of the sheets